# how to get the value of a particular checkbox if it is checked when submitting a button?

Tags: php, jquery

I have two divs containing the same checkbox with the same name,class and id. When I am selecting the checkbox of a particular div , it should alert the value of that checkbox when submitting a button.

Example :

```
<div>

    <input type="checkbox" class="snowplay" id="snowplayy" name="snowplay" value="1">
</div>
<div>

    <input type="checkbox" class="snowplay" id="snowplayy" name="snowplay" value="2">
</div>
<div>

    <input type="submit" class="submit" id="submit" name="submit" />
</div>
```

When I am clicking any of the two checkboxes, and then submitting the button, I want to alert the value of the checkbox of that particular checkbox. Can anyone say how to do this ?

Comment: `ID should be unique`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.submit').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
    //alert($('.snowplay:checked').val()) //single value
  $('.snowplay:checked').each(function() {//iterate over 
    alert($(this).val()) // many value

  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>

  <input type="checkbox" class="snowplay" id="snowplayy" name="snowplay" value="1">
</div>
<div>

  <input type="checkbox" class="snowplay" id="snowplayy1" name="snowplay" value="2">

</div>

<div>

  <input type="submit" class="submit" id="submit" name="submit" />

</div>
```

1. Use this `.snowplay:checked` checkbox with class snowplay that is checked
2. Change your id to be unique

Answer (score 0):

Id should be unique. So here i removed the id Attribute :).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#submit').click(function(){
$('.snowplay:checked').each(function(){
alert($(this).val())
});

});

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>

    <input type="checkbox" class="snowplay"  name="snowplay" value="1">
</div>
<div>

    <input type="checkbox" class="snowplay"  name="snowplay" value="2">
</div>
<div>

    <input type="submit" class="submit" id="submit" name="submit" />
</div>

</body>
</html>
```